# need help writing this compound trigger

Tags: sql, plsql

i have a column in my table that i need to update on insert or update, i can't do it with a simple trigger because the new value has to be SELECTED from the same table and other tables (which would generate `trigger is mutating` error).
my solution was to use a compound trigger, after a little bit of documentation i wrote this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_contract_n FOR
    INSERT OR UPDATE ON contract
COMPOUND TRIGGER
    v_n VARCHAR(70);
    AFTER EACH ROW IS BEGIN
        v_n := object_contract(:new.id_contract);
    END AFTER EACH ROW;
    AFTER STATEMENT IS BEGIN
        UPDATE contract
        SET
            n = v_n
        WHERE
            id_contract = :new.id_contract;
    END AFTER STATEMENT;
END update_contract_n;
```

the function `object_contract()` joins 4 tables one of which is the table `contract` and returns a varchar.
when i compile the trigger code i get this error :

```
pls-00679 trigger binds not allowed in before/after statement section
```

but i don't know what i'm doing wrong since the variable binding was done in `AFTER EACH ROW` section not in `AFTER STATEMENT`.
any help would be appreciated (fixing or rewriting the code), a simple guide on how to use a compound trigger would also be appreciated.

EDIT:
i found the problem, i was referencing `:new.id_contract` in `AFTER STATEMENT` and i fixed it, but now i am getting  `table is mutating trigger/function may not see it`
how can i fix that?

Comment: You're referencing `new.id_contract` in UPDATE statement of **AFTER STATEMENT** part of the trigger.

Comment: You still get the mutating error because your COMPOUND trigger uses the same logic as the original one: you execute the offending code in AFTER EACH ROW. The idea of a compound trigger to solve the mutating error is to collect the information regarding the rows to be updated in the AFTER EACH ROW part but execute the code in the AFTER STATEMENT part. To do that you need to declare TABLE OF variables to collect the needed information.

Comment: so i can't collect the data in a simple variable?

Comment: Here is a very good article by Steven Feuerstein on compound triggers. You can probably copy that logic: http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-rid-of-mutating-table-trigger.html